# Airflow Docker. Executing Windows Python Scripts

Tags: python, docker, airflow, arcgis

Resurrecting this question as the answer provided doesn't solve the author's problem:
[Execute windows python scripts via airflow docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53499974/execute-windows-python-scripts-via-airflow-docker-container/78149247#78149247)

How to get Airflow on Docker to execute the scripts as if they're running in Windows using one of my python environments?

i.e.

```
C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/ESRI/conda/envs/arcgispro-py3-clone/python.exe C:\sample-code\test.py
```

Used PythonOperator and modules within DAGS folder to run the script within a container. However, I need to run the scripts located on my local drive via Airflow Docker.

Comment: If the other question doesn't have good answers, consider putting a bounty to raise more awareness of it. Don't repost the question as it will be closed as a duplicate.